# Grails app fails to load on tomcat

Tags: spring, grails, tomcat7

I have some spring beans defined using groovy dsl and "plugin-config". There are also libraries on classpath with regular spring xml contex.

So I put to resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    importBeans("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
}
```

When I run app using "grails run-app" command it works. But when I deploy the war to Tomcat 7 then it fails (points to https://github.com/daniel-lima/grails-plugin-config-plugin/blob/master/src/java/org/grails/plugin/config/AbstractConfigHelper.java - line 340):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] 
- this expression must be true
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this expression must be true
```

Anyone?

Comment: Isn't the [issue related in the Github project](https://github.com/daniel-lima/grails-plugin-config-plugin/pull/1)?

Comment: Well, it depends. It might be something wrong with configuration in grails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in plugin-config grails plugin at 0.1.5 version. It has been already fixed in version 0.1.8.

We using quartz2 plugin which enforced 0.1.5 version to our app.

So I have excluded plugin-config from quartz2 and added latest version.