# Upgrading from grails 2.0.4 to 2.2.4 - problems with transactions

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I've got an existing Grails project for 2.0.1 that works perfectly.

I'm looking to upgrade to GGTS 3.4.0.M1 which comes with grails 2.2.4. Have imported my existing project, its identified the difference of grails version, I selected to upgrade this project to 2.2.4 which have completed ok.

Whenever I run the project (either run-app or test-app for integration tests), it fails with the below stack. I've gone through the Grails docs, particularly the 'upgrade from a previous version' and believe I've covered everything I need to. But scratching my head as to what the problem here is.

Any suggestions?

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
Loading default beans for environment=DEVELOPMENT

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

| Error 2013-10-09 17:53:22,446 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.transaction.handling.TransactionHandlingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this expression must be true
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.transaction.handling.TransactionHandlingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this expression must be true
    Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this expression must be true
->> 340 | newInstance in org.grails.plugin.config.AbstractConfigHelper$ConfigObjectProxy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   111 | doCall   in org.grails.plugin.config.DefaultConfigHelper$_enhanceConfigObjectClass_closure3
|     1 | run . .  in Script1
|   160 | afterPropertiesSet in grails.plugin.transaction.handling.TransactionHandlingPostProcessor
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't come across this in my initial search, [grails-app-fails-to-load-on-tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047226/grails-app-fails-to-load-on-tomcat), but upgrading the plugin-config from 0.1.5 to 0.1.8 did the trick (amended BuildConfig.groovy).